# Botón para Generar un Número aleatorio en una celda de una Hoja de Calculo de Google

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Hacer el botón con una imagen y a esta imagen asignarle un script, ok todo correcto hasta aquí.

Necesito ayuda para generar el Script que agregue en determinada celda el valor aleatorio que se genera entre cierto rango determinado algo así como la función `=ALEATORIO.ENTRE(celda1;celda2);` ... pero esta función se ejecuta cada vez que se actualiza la pagina, por ello quiero hacer un botón para que solo se genere el numero aleatorio cuando le de aa este botón.

He estado estudiando el Google Apps Script, pero aun no soy muy diestro si me pueden ayudar seria genial. Hasta ahora lo que voy entendiendo que debo proceder debo crear la función, debo indicar en la hoja que estoy en este caso he colocado `.getActiveSpreadsheet();` para que tome la hoja activa sin tener que ponerle el Id de la hoja.
Ahora debo proceder a que reconozca las dos celdas donde esta el rango mínimo y máximo por la que se va a generar el aleatorio; en este caso la celda B2 y la celda B3 indican los correspondientes.
Por lo que he visto debo especificar los auxiliares para poder manejar la hoja y sus datos, la variable sheet hace referencia a la primera hoja del documento (la hoja o libro con índice 0), ahora necesito colocar el resultado de los números aleatorios en la celda B6

```
function Sorteo(){
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sorteo");
 var cell = sheet.getRange("B6");
 var rango_min = sheet.getRange("B2");
 var rango_max = sheet.getRange("B3");
 cell.setValue(Math.floor((Math.random()*(rango_max - rango_min)) + rango_min));
}
```

¿Sí hasta ahora voy bien, como puedo hacer para que esto ocurra cuando pulse el botón?

// Edito //
He corrido el código sin mas, no le puse nada de `onClick()` que pensé que necesitaría al parecer, ha corrido directo, pero...

Me ha dado como resultado en la celda correcta el siguiente mensaje: `#¡NÚM!`

// Vuelvo a Editar //
El error se ha corregido después de la sugerencia del usuario Ruben.
Le he dado muchas veces a sortear y no se ha salido de los limites, si alguien mas puede verificar que la formula de sorteo sea "correcta" le agradezco.
Agregue la función al botón y ha quedado muy bonito!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De la pregunta

> Si hasta ahora voy bien...

No es así. Debes cambiar

```
var rango_min = sheet.getRange("B2");
var rango_max = sheet.getRange("B3");
```

a

```
var rango_min = sheet.getRange("B2").getValue();
var rango_max = sheet.getRange("B3").getValue();
```

de lo contrario habrá un error en la siguiente línea

```
cell.setValue(Math.floor((Math.random()*(rango_max - rango_min) + rango_min));
```

porque no puedes hacer operaciones aritméticas teniendo objetos Range como operandos

Consejo para facilitar la depuración de tus scripts: Procura evitar expresiones completas como parámetro de métodos como `setValue`, es mejor asignar la expresión compleja a una variable y luego usar esa variable como susodicho argumento, por ejemplo, podrías poner un `console.log` antes de la línea con el `setValue` para tener en la página de ejecuciones el resultado de tu expresión compleja.

Comment: ¡Vaya! Ha respondido super rápido, justo estaba probando el error que me ha dado, seguro es por lo que comentas, voy a proceder como explicas y les informo!

Comment: no he entendido muy bien el consejo para la depuración, lo he estado leyendo detenidamente pero aun no entiendo como debería proceder para manejar los datos de una manera .. optima se podría decir ?

Comment: @HeckDan `var value = Math.floor((Math.random()*(rango_max - rango_min) + rango_min); cell.setValue(value);`